# Listar registros condicionales en base a un promedio con avg

Tags: mysql, sql

quisiera saber cómo listar registros de un promedio que obtuve con la función AVG, necesito listar los promedios que sean igual o menor a 30%, esto es lo que tengo por el momento:

```
select id_producto, nombre, descripcion, stock, avg(porcentage) as porcentaje_promedio 
from tabla1
where ####;
```

por obvias razones no puedo especificar "porcentaje_promedio" en el where ya que no es una columna como tal, ¿alguna recomendación?

Comment: Por favor añade la estructura de tu tabla, la consulta SQL que llevas, así como una muestra de los datos para poder ayudarte mejor, checa de paso [ask]. Saludos

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cuando tratas de filtrar por el valor de una columna calculada con alguna función de agregación, como en este caso AVG; entonces debes usar **`HAVING`** de este modo:

```
select id_producto, 
       nombre, 
       descripcion, 
       stock, 
       avg(porcentage) as porcentaje_promedio 
from tabla1
group by id_producto, 
         nombre, 
         descripcion, 
         stock
HAVING porcentaje_promedio <= 30
```

La diferencia entre **`HAVING`** y **`WHERE`** es que el primero trabaja sobre los valores calculados, mientras que el segundo sobre los valores reales o que existen antes de hacer el cálculo.

Considera además como te mencionaba en los comentarios que primero iría

- `WHERE`
- `GROUP BY`
- `HAVING`
- `ORDER BY`

**Referencias**

- [having](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html)

Comment: Entiendo, si me permites hacerte otra pregunta, ¿puedo usar HAVING enseguida de la cláusula WHERE?

Comment: No entiendo para que ocuparías WHERE, si lo explicas mejor se te puede apoyar

Comment: Lo que pasa es que en otra consulta tengo que traer datos de otra tabla, es decir hago un JOIN donde el id de la tabla 1 coincida con el id de la tabla 2 pero respetando el HAVING.

Comment: @AlmaG entonces en tu consulta primero debe estar el `WHERE` luego el `GROUP BY` y al final el `HAVING` como te mostré

Comment: @Aprendiz, espero no te moleste mi edición

Comment: Para nada @PatricioMoracho, pues como ando desde el móvil me resultaba difícil editarla agregando lo faltante